# Performance Tuning on CartoDB

Tags: carto, performance

What kind of tuning can be done on your own cartodb instance to speed things up (outside of sql query optimization and indices)? Is there any documentation on this? If the records do not change, could that make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from SQL query optimization and indexes, which you already covered, there's not much. Here are a few things I can think of which might be useful in certain circumstances:

- If your records don't change I would expect that to result in a minor performance boost, because CartoDB uses Varnish pretty heavily for caching, so keeping the records in your table constant should improve caching performance.
- CartoDB's tiler Windshaft will also cache styling information, so if you avoid changing your visualization styling you should see a small speed boost.
- Your CartoDB performance can be affected by the other accounts on your database host; in extreme situations you could try to get yourself onto a different host by opening a new account, but this isn't guaranteed to work and could leave you worse off--you'd probably be better off opening a support ticket.

This isn't documented anywhere that I know of, except in the source code.